# Plot3d plots an empty graph

Tags: plotting, functions, summation

So I'm trying to graph a wave-type function using the following code:

```
g[x_, y_] := Sum[Sin[(n\[Pi]*5)/10]*Sin[(m\[Pi]*5)/10]*Sin[(n\[Pi]x)/10]*Sin[(m\[Pi]y)/10], {n, 1, 20}, {m, 1, 20}];

Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]
```

However, the plot just shows up empty. I also tried it without the semicolon and nothing changed. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Put spaces between symbols to indicate multiplication.  `n\[Pi]x` is not the same as `n \[Pi] x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in your code has to do with not leaving proper spaces between the letters you used. Hence, mathematica recognized $n \pi x$ as one variable.

A nice way to check this in future computations, is to also observe what happens to the colors of the variables when it did not work and when it works. Do you observe anything?

If coded with the proper spaces, you get a nice result.

Try to copy and paste the following ans check for yourself

```
g[x_, y_] := 
  Sum[Sin[(n \[Pi]*5)/10]*Sin[(m \[Pi]*5)/10]*Sin[(n \[Pi] x)/10]*
    Sin[(m \[Pi] y)/10], {n, 1, 20}, {m, 1, 20}];

Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver, thanks so much!

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)

Comment: The function will evaluate quicker if you change the definition to `g[x_, y_] = Simplify[Sum[Sin[(n*Pi*5)/10] * Sin[(m*Pi*5)/10] * Sin[(n*Pi*x)/10] * Sin[(m*Pi*y)/10], {n, 1, 20}, {m, 1, 20}]]`